# Transformations with c++ openGL

Tags: c++, opengl

i'm working on simple room using C++ openGL libraries, 
i have a problem with transformations,

First my system is working like :

Press w: for moving along -z axis, s: moving along +z axis, a: moving left, d:moving right .

Press Left & Right key : rotate around y axis , 
Press Up & down key : rotate around x axis.

And here is my code for combining the rotation and translation together.

```
glm::vec3 _camVelocity = glm::vec3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
glm::vec3 _camRotation = glm::vec3(0,0,0);

SDL_Event evnt;
   while (SDL_PollEvent(&evnt))
   {
       switch (evnt.type)
       {
           case SDL_KEYDOWN:
               switch(evnt.key.keysym.sym) {
                   case SDLK_w:
                       _camera.translate(-_camVelocity.x * sin(glm::radians(_camRotation.y)), 0.0,- _camVelocity.z * cos(glm::radians(_camRotation.y)));
                       break;
                   case SDLK_s:
                       _camera.translate(_camVelocity.x * sin(glm::radians(_camRotation.y)), 0.0, _camVelocity.z * cos(glm::radians(_camRotation.y)));
                       break;
                   case SDLK_a:
                       _camera.translate(-_camVelocity.x * cos(glm::radians(-_camRotation.y)), 0.0, -_camVelocity.z * sin(glm::radians(-_camRotation.y)));
                       break;
                   case SDLK_d:
                       _camera.translate(_camVelocity.x * cos(glm::radians(-_camRotation.y)), 0.0, _camVelocity.z * sin(glm::radians(-_camRotation.y)));
                       break;
                   case SDLK_LEFT:
                       _camRotation.y += 1;
                       break;
                   case SDLK_RIGHT:
                       _camRotation.y -= 1;
                       break;
                   case SDLK_UP:
                       _camRotation.x += 1;
                       break;
                   case SDLK_DOWN:
                       _camRotation.x -= 1;
                       break;
       }
       break;
    }


   _camera.setRotation(0, 1, 1, 1);
   _camera.rotate(_camRotation.x, 1, 0, 0);
   _camera.rotate(_camRotation.y, 0, 1, 0);

  }}
```

for the declaration of used functions :

```
void Camera3D::setRotation(float rotationAngle, float x, float y, float z){
    rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(rotationAngle), glm::vec3(x, y, z));
    updateViewMatrix();
 }

void Camera3D::translate(float x, float y, float z){
    translationMatrix = glm::translate(translationMatrix, glm::vec3(x, y, z));
    updateViewMatrix();
 }

void Camera3D::rotate(float rotationAngle, float x, float y, float z){
    rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(rotationMatrix, glm::radians(rotationAngle), glm::vec3(x, y, z));
    updateViewMatrix();
 }

void Camera3D::updateViewMatrix() {
    viewMatrix = rotationMatrix * translationMatrix;
 }
```

For the uniform matrix which i send it to vertex shader to be multiplied by all vertices :

```
projectMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), float (4/3), 0.01f, 1000.0f);

sendMatrix = projectMatrix * viewMatrix;
```

Now, this code works perfectly with the room , but only when i look at any corner of the room (to face my face) the translation is flipped !

when i press (w & s) i go through x axis ! and (a & d) i go through z axis !

i can't know why !

Comment: Try chaning `viewMatrix = rotationMatrix * translationMatrix;` to `viewMatrix = translationMatrix * rotationMatrix;` in updateViewMatrix.

Comment: i found my mistake , the negative sign for angles must be for (w & s) not for (a & d) , thank you!